# How to provide source map in Nodejs VM

Tags: javascript, node.js, source-maps, native-module, nodevm

I am evaluating `javascript` bundled source code in `nodejs` using the below code

```js
const javascriptCode = "..."
const javascriptSourceMap = "..."
const wrapper = NativeModule.wrap(javascriptCode);
const script = new vm.Script(wrapper, {
    displayErrors: true
});
script.runInNewContext();
```

When there is an error in the source code I get errors like this because no source maps are provided

```
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at VueComponent.testSomething (evalmachine.<anonymous>:43112:7)
    at VueComponent.testSomethingAgain (evalmachine.<anonymous>:43109:12
```

How to provide source maps to VM so that I can get proper filenames instead of `evalmachine.<anonymous>`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try

```
require('vm').runInThisContext('console.log(2);\ninvalidJsHere ?= 1;', 'foobar.js');
```

then you get

```
foobar.js:2
invalidJsHere ?= 1;
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `vm.Script` does not support source maps in stack traces as of Node 21.7.1. See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/52102